# update parameter in scala function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

In spark mllib naive bayes code, how can it do this?

`c._2 += v.toBreeze`

`v: Vector` is a parameter of mergeValue function, and we can not reassign a `val`. But why there is `c._2 += v.toBreeze` in  source code?

Here is source code:

```
mergeValue = (c: (Long, BDV[Double]), v: Vector) => {
    requireNonnegativeValues(v)
    (c._1 + 1L, c._2 += v.toBreeze)},
```

Answer (score 1):

The way it is written is not an assignment but rather a method for returning a new vector with the element added. Essentially, `c._2 += v.toBreeze` is more formally written as this `(c._2).+=(v.toBreeze)`.

If you look at the API for [`breeze.linalg.DenseVector`](http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/index.html#breeze.linalg.DenseVector) (which the `BDV` class is aliased from), you'll notice there is a method `+=` which prepends the vector with an element. This is the method being applied in this case.

Going back to your example, this means that the code in question (the second argument for a `combineByKey()` is creating a function that increments a `Long` (`c._1 + 1L`) as well as aggregates an `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` into a `breeze.linalg.DenseVector` (`c._2 += v.toBreeze`). The way that vector aggregation happens is with the `+=` method returning a new `DenseVector`.

Comment: Thank you very much,I got it ,